# How to find the integral for $\int 2^{\sin{x}}\cos{x}\;\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

What would be the ideal approach in finding the integral for:

$$
\int 2^{\sin{x}}\cos{x}\;\mathrm{d}x
$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $u=\sin x$, $du=\cos x\, dx$, and $dx=\frac{du}{\cos x}$, then
\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
\int 2^{\sin{x}}\cos{x}\;dx&=\int 2^{u}\cancel{\cos{x}}\;\frac{du}{\cancel{\cos x}}\\
&=\int 2^u\; du\\
&=\int e^{u\ln 2}\; du\qquad;\;\;a^b=e^{b\ln a}\\
&=\frac{e^{u\ln 2}}{\ln 2}+C\qquad\quad;\;\int e^{ax}\; dx=\frac{e^{ax}}{a}+C\\
&=\frac{e^{\sin x\ln 2}}{\ln 2}+C\\
&=\frac{2^{\sin{x}}}{\ln 2}+C
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Put $\cos{x}$ under derivative:

> $$\int 2^{\sin{x}}\cos{x}\;\mathrm{d}x = \int 2^{\sin{x}}\;\mathrm{d}{\sin{x}} = \int 2^u\;\mathrm{d}{u} = \dfrac{2^u}{\ln{2}} = \dfrac{2^{\sin{x}}}{\ln{2}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: let $u = sinx$ , then transfer it to integral with respect to $u$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Rewrite $2^{\sin(x)}$ as $e^{\sin(x) \log(2)}$ and recognize that $\cos(x)$ is almost the derivative of the exponent.